# Simple search form error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement a simple search form that searches the db for keywords whose content is being searched.

My view has this form:

```
<%= form_tag search_keywords_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

My controller has these:

```
def search
    @keywords =  Keyword.search(params[:search])
end

def show
    @keyword = Keyword.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @keyword }
    end
end
```

Model keyword.rb:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
    Rails.logger.debug("debug::Searching for" + search)
    @keyword = Keyword.find_all_by_content(search)
    end
end
```

Now, whenever I try to run a search I get this error :

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in KeywordsController#show
Couldn't find Keyword with id=search

Now from what I understand, something is messing up the show method, but I don't get why or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check your parameters passing to server after you click on `submit_tag`. It would be better if you post here

Comment: "utf8"=>"✓",
"search"=>"aaa",
"id"=>"search"

Comment: did you added routes for `search`? Can you show your `routes`?

Comment: your form is getting routed to your `show` action, not your `search` action... check the form and your routes

Comment: As far as I can tell the routes should be fine. However, query is SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords" WHERE "keywords"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "search"]]. I'm not trying to search by id though, but by the "content" field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't added routes for `search` action. You can add routes for search as follows:

```
resources :keywords do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

Comment: My routes are set up just as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

In your keyword.rb

replace

```
 @keyword = Keyword.find_all_by_content(search)
```

With,

```
 @keyword = Keyword.find_all_by_content("#{search}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the search functionality you need to use find() in a way it raises exceptions, that is, passing the id you want to find.

```
  def show
        begin
          @keyword = Keyword.find(params[:id])
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html # show.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @keyword }
          end
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
           flash[:notice] = "Wrong keyword"
           redirect_to :action => 'index'
        end  
    end
```

Comment: Find return nil when no record found as mentioned in given link documentation: (Link)[documentationhttp://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html]